# Is it possible to convert regular R code to its pipe version?

Tags: r, dplyr, syntax, pipe

Is there any add-in or package that allows to transform code from a regular R version to its pipe version ?

```r
library(dplyr)
# Regular R version
data <- mtcars
data <- mutate(data, cyl2 = - cyl)
data2 <- subset(data, cyl2 < - 3) # I use a non-dplyr verb on purpose

# Piped version
data2 <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(cyl2 = - cyl) %>% 
  subset(cyl2 < - 3)
```

Comment: Note that the piped version is not identical to the first, the `data` object is lost here that could break other things in a script. There are many edge cases to consider, for example which pipe to use, what should happen to `<<-`, function declarations etc. I reckon you could get close to the desired behavior using `rstudioapi`'s `insertText` and some regexes like `(?<=\\().*,(?=.)`. Let us know when you have some code that (doesn't ?) work!

Comment: Yes, fair point regarding the two codes.

Comment: I will look up at `insertText` then, but I hoped that contributors to the `tidyverse` package had already thought about this problem and perhaps found a solution

Comment: The only subject I found about `insertText` is this question https://community.rstudio.com/t/using-rstudioapi-to-create-a-new-file-and-insert-text/41549. Do you have others, because the help for this function is really thin

Comment: `?insertText` has some examples. For (addin) packages that transform user code using `rstudioapi`, see [styler](https://github.com/r-lib/styler/) or [datapasta](https://github.com/MilesMcBain/datapasta/blob/master/R/vector_paste.R).

Answer (score 0):

There is no such package/add-on that I know of. It's fairly self-explanatory why: the software would have no way of consistently knowing what is pipeable because functions can both place their arguments in different orders and also name their arguments something else.

For example, consider `data.frame(x=5) %>% foo()`. It could well be that `foo(., arg)` produces a different result than `foo(arg, .)`. Even if the software somehow looked at the names of the arguments and made an educated guess, such as "any argument named `data` contains the data", (a) that assumption may be incorrect (perhaps `df` needs the data or `data` needs the dimensionality of the data) and (b) the inconsistency would presumably be enough that it would require a lot of continuous, presumably-human checking and continuous maintenance, and (c) it's not a well-defined problem in itself: `dplyr::left_join(x1, x2)` can be accomplished with `x1 %>% left_join(., x2)`, `x2 %>% left_join(x1, .)`, etc.

Comment: I don't understand the first part of your comment. I want to go from vanilla R to pipe R. Not the other way round

Comment: By the way, I don't see the problem in converting `data.frame(x=5) %>% foo()`  to `foo(data.frame(x=5))` since the piped `data.frame(x=5) ` is assigned to the first argument

Comment: `foo()` is an arbitrary function with arbitrary arguments. Consider: `rnorm(sd = 2, n = 1000)` does not produce the same distribution as `2 %>% rnorm(n=1000)`

Comment: @socialscientist, if arguments to a function are unnamed they will follow the default order, when the function was defined.  For example in `rnorm(1000,10,2)` R knows the arguments are n, mean, sd, in that order. So in theory, you could have functionality that converted the code when arguments are unnamed. This would be a kind of metaprogramming thing, an IDE functionality, which I never heard of